# Are two commas needed in this sentence?

Tags: commas

Could someone tell me that is this possible to write **moreover** between two commas?

Therefore, it is concluded that the two herbs named garlic and the black seeds may be good alternative choices for chemical drugs`, moreover,` these two anti-parasitic Herbs can be considered as harmless and affordable additives.....

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have no time to check any references, but I think you need at least a semi-colon (instead of a comma) before *moreover*, or you could break them into two sentences, or else what you have is a run-on sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is common to write it this way. If you think how you would naturally speak this, there would be a pause before and after *moreover*.

There are some example sentences you can check here: [moreover](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/moreover)